# Why is it that webpack loads two different jQuery instances?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, webpack

I'm trying to use a jquery plugin, intl-tel-input , on a angular1/webpack app, the plugin is installed under node_modules.

When I load the app, not only the initialization of the plugin states that it is not defined, but when I inspect the global namespace, I find two instances of jQuery loaded, my reasoning here is that one of them has the plugin, the other does not.

This gets stranger, when instead of loading the plugin file, from under the node_modules, I load it from a custom directory, or under bower_components, everything seems to *magically* work.
So my solution eventually, was to just install the plugin under bower and remove it from node_modules.

I have been going around trying to understand why without success, I don't understand why this odd behavior, would someone care to explain it to me?

relevant files:

- [app.js](https://gist.github.com/darkbls/ece3be3def744ed3f48e049951fb3446#file-app-js), app init
- [webpack.config.js](https://gist.github.com/darkbls/ece3be3def744ed3f48e049951fb3446#file-webpack-config-js)